# How to get the Role of the currently logged in user

Tags: javascript

Is there any possibilities to get the Role of the current user who has logged in to my application by using javascript or some other ways

Comment: :Where is this javascript located?? VF page/ side bar component?

Comment: its in the sidebar component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the user role name in sidebar component , use the below code in your side bar component:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var sid = getCookie('sid');
  var server = "https://" + window.location.host + "/services/Soap/u/27.0";
      //initiate the connection
  sforce.connection.init(sid, server);

  var currentUser = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
  alert('the profile Id is '+ currentUser.profileId);
  var result = sforce.connection.query('select name from profile where id=\''+currentUser.profileId+'\'');
  var arrayResults = result.getArray("records");
  alert('the name of the profile is '+ arrayResults[0].Name);

</script>
```

Comment: i am getting ` The role is null `

Comment: Have you assigned any role to the current user?

Comment: one question if I log in it should say `" System Adminstrastor "` rite

Comment: Thats the profile and not Role.. Role and profile are 2 different entities..

Comment: I have updated my post with the proper code you will get the profile name now..

Comment: How can i add this to a controller , any suggestions

Comment: Do you want to call a controller class (which will have the above logic) from your sidebar component?

Comment: yes can you help me

Comment: Yes you can call the controller class, you would need to use the sforce.apex.execute(http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_and_ajax.htm) to call your apex class from the javascript from the sidebar component. The examples in the link are pretty simple. You can try those examples

Comment: If all you want to do is display some information in the sidebar, then I would strictly suggest you to embed a VF page in the sidebar component. You can create a VF page which will show all the information + you have the flexibility of adding the controller there itself. You can embed a VF page in you sidebar component using the <iframe src="/apex/yourVFpageName" height="" width=""/> tag. set the appropriate height and width attribute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9693/discussion-between-aravind30790-and-thegreatdanton)

Comment: How can i get the session id in the html area component

Comment: updated the conversation

Answer (score 0):

you can get the currently logged in userRoleId from UserInfo.getUserRoleId method.

with this role Id Query the  userRole object to get Name and other information about the role.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the reply i got the role of the user by using `{!$Profile.Name}`

Comment: I think then you require the profile name then. But originally u have mentioned the role name is required. Also using javascript if you want u need to query for the same.

Comment: sorry my mistake , @danton has already given an answer